# Quota Limit Exceeded - How to increase Youtube API V3 quota

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I'm having an issue with YouTube data API V3. We have been using YouTube Data API V3 in one of our mobile applications.

Recently we've started getting more traffics in our application and our quota use is capped at 40-50M request points, Hence  any subsequent API calling throwing this errors:

code: 403,
message: "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your [quota](/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota)."

How can we increase/buy extra API limit for this project? Recently we created a billing account and added payment method for this project.

Can anybody please suggests how we can increase the extra limit?

I'm ready to pay for additional quota if needed.

Comment: are you adding quotaUser to your requests?  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/standard_parameters

Comment: I'm using default quota limit per user which is 3,000 requests/second/user. But I want more than 50M (Free quota limit for now) request points per day. Is there any way to increase this free quota limit (50M)?

Comment: no the quota limit per user is not one that you can change.

Comment: In the Developer console, if you have billing enabled it allows you to apply for higher quota. However, (I just checked)clicking on "Apply for higher quota" shows a "We are not approving Quota requests" screen. Hence, I'd suggest you to implement and use [Exponential Backoff](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/backoff?hl=en) to be able to better utilize your quota.